# Javascript - trying to create a dynamic combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, combobox

im trying to create a combobox that contain a table from database

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <fieldset>
        <select class="select2_single form-control">
            <option class="default" value=""></option>
            <?php
            $tampil=mysql_query("SELECT ID_KRITERIA, NAMA_KRITERIA FROM KRITERIA ORDER BY NAMA_KRITERIA");
            while($w=mysql_fetch_array($tampil))    {
                echo '<option value="' . $w['ID_KRITERIA'] . '">' . $w['NAMA_KRITERIA'] . '</option>';  }
            ?>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
```

and then I want to duplicate this combobox everytime I click a button
here is my Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    // set an on click on the button
        $("#newKriteria").click(function () {
            var newComboBox = $("fieldset").find("select").clone();
            $('#step-3 div:eq(0)').after("<div class='item form-group'><label class='control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'>&nbsp;</label><div class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>"+newComboBox+"</div></div>");
            $(newComboBox).select2({
                placeholder: "Pilih Masukan",
                allowClear: true
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

I have tried following some way

1. with following javascript above, my page is showing [object Object] everytime I click the button
2. using .html() insted of .clone() = the combobox only show the value (not with the css)

is there any right way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`newComboBox` is a jQuery object, that's why you end in having [Object object], try `newComboBox.val()` instead. It should returns you the value of the select you cloned (is clone needed anyway ?)

Comment: It create some space, but not show any combobox. 
Yes, I mean clone() is the best way I can found until now,
I tried create a combobox with after('<select id="something"></select>') then call the combobox value through id, but my combobox still didnt show any option/value